# Percentage of Random Calls from Multithreaded Program

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is my Text File, test1.txt.

```
AutoRefreshStoreCategories  70%  1  16  2060    10053   10106   10111
CrossPromoEditItemRule      20%  1  10107   10108   10109
CrossPromoManageRules       10%  1  10107   10108   10109
```

I wanted to write a multithreaded program which can read the file line by line and print each numbers in a line by splitting on whitespace(I have done this part). And in the above file I have some percentage specified next to Command Name, Example for the first line, it has 70% next to **AutoRefreshStoreCategories**. So I want 70% of random calls go to the first line. In the same way second line has 20%, so 20% of random calls go to second line. And lastly for the third line, 10% of random calls go to third line. 
And for each line basically I want to print the numbers they have in each line.

So I wrote a multithreaded program below, but that program just print the numbers in each line that's it, It doesn't take into the accound the percentage of random calls. I am not sure what logic I can have so that from by using that multithreaded program, I can specify this much percentage of random calls go to first line, or second line or third line.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public class ExcelRead {

    private static Integer threadSize = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= threadSize; i++) {
            new Thread(new ThreadTask(i)).start();
        }
    }
}


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;

    public ThreadTask(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing\\test1.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] s = sCurrentLine.split("\\s+");
                for (String split : s) {
                if(split.matches("\\d*"))
                System.out.println(split);
            }
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Or more generally a "learning exercise"?

Comment: btw, calling run() does not start a new Thread. You must call start() instead

Comment: I know calling run will not start a new thread, I was just running it in order.

Comment: What's the point of instantiating a new Thread then?

Comment: I have changed that to start. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not sure what logic I can have so that from by using that multithreaded program, I can specify this much percentage of random calls go to first line, or second line or third line. Any help will be appreciated.

Since, this appears to be homework (or self learning) I suggest that you **think about** how you would do this if you were pretending to be the computer.  One part is to read the javadoc for the `Random` class, and figure out how to map a random `int` value to fit your percentage ranges.

---

As a footnote, I'm puzzled about what you are trying to achieve by making this a multi-threaded program.  Perhaps you could explain.  To my mind it is (currently) only making a simple task more complicated ... with no performance benefit.

Comment: Actually I have made this question simple enough because on the basis of this I have to do a complicated task. So that is the reason I have narrowed down my question to very simple case as I need to make percentage of random calls basis on the threadSize. Any code snippet will be appreciated.